# Why do different people perceive the colors of the Northern Lights (Aurora Borealis) differently?

Tags: human-physiology, vision, human-eye

A few days ago, I was in Norway with a group of about 20 people. We were fortunate enough to witness an impressive display of the Northern Lights that lasted several hours. The next day, we discovered that while some of us saw the Aurora as clearly green, others perceived it as white or grayish (the split was about 50/50).

Our cell phone photos showed bright greens and reds. I understand that the cameras used long exposure times (about 4 seconds), allowing their sensors to capture much more light than our eyes. However, I’m puzzled as to why different people saw different colors.

Here are a few things to note:

- There was no obvious correlation between the colors seen and factors such as age or gender. For instance, I am 53 years old and saw distinct colors that others, both younger and older, could not see.
- We were all in the same location, far from city lights or car headlights. We watched the sky for over an hour, so our eyes were likely as dark-adapted as possible.
- None of us are color blind.
- No one saw the red color that appeared as bright as the green in the pictures we took.

The only somewhat reasonable explanation for the different experiences was the difference in pupil diameter between individuals (a smaller diameter means that less light enters the eye, so scotopic vision may be prevalent). However, it seems that the pupillary light reflex is only a [minor part](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adaptation_(eye)#Ambient_light_response) of adaptation to ambient light.

So, what could be the main factor influencing the varied color perception of the Northern Lights?

Comment: Remember your cell phone has its own colour balancing too.